# firestore auth rule: for google signed in client

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to establish a rule to fetch firestore data, that can be accessed by a google signed in client.
So the problem I'm facing is when I'm using this rule

```
match /helpers/customer/data/{document=**}{
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
}
```

An error pops in logcat

> onFailure:
>   Errorcom.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException:
>   PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

also it is only working when I'm using

```
match /helpers/customer/data/{document=**}{
  allow read: if true;
}
```

That means the path is write.

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

    if(acct != null){
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Database Working");
        mFirestoreDB
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Database not Working");
    }
```

What I need is a rule where I can allow only a google signed in user to access.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the minimal code that is needed to get that error message?

Comment: Okay I've updated the questoin

Comment: How do you initialize `mFirestoreDB`? Does it point to a specific collection?

Comment: private CollectionReference mFirestoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("helpers/customer/data");  this is it

Comment: here data is a collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing in with Google does not automatically sign the user in with Firebase. You will need to also sign them in with Firebase Authentication, before your security rules will have its `auth` variable set.

From the [Firebase documentation in signing in with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase):

> ```
> private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
>     Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
>
>     AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
>     mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
>             .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
>                     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>                         // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
>                         Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
>                         FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
>                         updateUI(user);
>                     } else {
>                         // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
>                         Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
>                         Toast.makeText(GoogleSignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
>                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                         updateUI(null);
>                     }
>
>                     // ...
>                 }
>             });
> }
> ```

But I recommend you read the entire page I linked.